# How to make unorder list with random numbers in html

Tags: html, html-lists

this is my data:

1. this line..
2. this line..

3.2 this line..

3.A: this line..

4. this line..

currently i am using this way:

```
1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;">this line..</li>
</ul>

3.A:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;">this line..</li>
</ul>
```

im getting output like this:

```
**----------

****--------------

**-------
```

I want like this:

```
**    ----------

****  --------------

**    -------
```

Comment: I'd love to help you but I have absolutely no idea what you want to achieve

Comment: sorry updated tag

Comment: i have to put &nbsp; spaces to put numbering on left and line on right i want my all rows start at same positions just like in unorder list and order list. where number comes in manner way

Comment: If you want to specify the elements of a list, and have them listed off with a random number at the beginning then you have to use PHP if you want it to be dynamic. You also wouldn't use <ul>.

Comment: or you could use javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my friend look at this:

1. `&nbsp;` to add 1 space.
2. `&ensp;` to add 2 spaces.
3. `&emsp;` to add 4 spaces.

or you on css :

- padding-left:5em

or

- margin-left:5em

in your code Your problem is unclear but I think that's what you want

```html
<body>

1.&emsp;
<ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;">&emsp;&emsp; this line..</li>
</ul>

3.A:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;">&emsp;&emsp; this line..</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

or you can replace li with ol like this

```html
<body>

1.
<ul>
    <ol style="list-style-type: none;">this line..</ol>
</ul>

3.A:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<ul>
    <ol style="list-style-type: none;">this line..</ol>
</ul>

</body>
```

`<ol>` Define an ordered list

`<ul>` Defines an unordered list